# Loading a 'bit' Mysql field from TypeOrm

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to map a Mysql bit data column against a `boolean` property with TypeOrm. I'm using the NestJs framework and can't figure out how to do it. As far as I've seen, the Mysql `bit` datatype is not supported by the framework, but I don't know any way to workaround it. According to [this discussion](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/642) it should be enough to declare a boolean typed field in the entity and do not decorate it with nothing but `@Column`:

```
  @Column()
  enable: boolean;
```

However, with this I get `true` value in every single instance of the entity. Also tried [adding](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/642#issuecomment-325034445) the `import 'reflect-metadata';` either in the entity and in `app.module.ts`, with the same result.

Another choice would be to use the `tinyint` type:

```
  @Column({
    type: 'tinyint',
  })
  enable: boolean;
```

With this, I get this kind of data, where the `data` field holds the current boolean value stored:

```
"enable":{"type":"Buffer","data":[1]}
```

Do I need to make some kind of hack to get this converted into a proper boolean value or is there another cleaner choice to do it?

---

**EDIT 1**

Changing the DB column data type to `int` seems to produce the proper output. However, it's not the most proper solution, since the `bit` type is the one that best suits here.

**Versions being used:**

- "@nestjs/typeorm": "5.1.0"
- "typeorm": "0.2.13"
- "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12"
- Mysql Engine: 5.7.25

---

**EDIT 2**

I've tried updating the `typeorm` related packages to their latest versions, the same keeps happening. Also with Mysql 8.0 engine. Tried also with these decorators:

```
  @Column()
  @IsBoolean()
  enable: boolean;
```

I'm in Xubuntu 16.04, BTW.

Comment: It looks to me like bit is supported as of this PR: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/3310

Comment: @JesseCarter tried updating `typeorm` and `@nestjs/typeorm` to their latest versions.. no luck. Also tried with Mysql engine 8.0, no luck. It keeps returning `true` for everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this issue with transformer:

```
import {ValueTransformer} from 'typeorm';
class BoolBitTransformer implements ValueTransformer {
  // To db from typeorm
  to(value: boolean | null): Buffer | null {
    if (value === null) {
      return null;
    }
    const res = new Buffer(1);
    res[0] = value ? 1 : 0;
    return res;
  }
  // From db to typeorm
  from(value: Buffer): boolean | null {
    if (value === null) {
      return null;
    }
    return value[0] === 1;
  }
}
```

And then used this transformer in bit/boolean columns:

```
  @Column({
    type: 'bit',
    nullable: false,
    default: () => `"'b'1''"`,
    name: 'can_read',
    transformer: new BoolBitTransformer()
  })
  can_read!: boolean;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm solving this in the following way

```js
  @Column({
    name: 'FIELD_NAME',
    type: 'bit',
    transformer: { from: (v: Buffer) => !!v.readInt8(0), to: (v) => v },
  })
  readonly field: boolean;
```

Answer (score 0):

improved the above code by adding the check:

```
 @Column({
    name: 'FIELD_NAME',
    type: 'bit',
    transformer: { from: (v: Buffer) => !!v?.readInt8(0), to: (v) => v },
  })
  field: boolean;
```

If this check is not added then it breaks when the bit value in db is null